# How can I make a button hidden only when the user is browsing with IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if I can make a button or a div tag only visible/invisible when the user is browsing with IE. I want to achieve that because I have Microsoft JScript runtime error: Access is denied. in IE when the user clicks on a button which triggers hidden asp.net fileupload control.

EDIT:
I have asp button :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSavePhoto" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and file upload control with class="hidden" (dysplay: none;):

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="uploadPhotoDialog" class="hidden" runat="server"/>
```

The idea is: when the user is browsing with IE - make fileupload visible and link button hidden.

Comment: Please learn how to accept answers ... if you have no idea what I'm talking about [click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170679) - This is your 3rd Question and you have not yet accepted an answer for any of them ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use conditional comments :

```
<!--[if IE]>
<div></div> // this is IE
<![endif]-->
```

or if not IE

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<div></div> // this is NOT IE
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

[Documentation here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

### Update

Using your ASP markup do the following :

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSavePhoto" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<!-- <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadPhotoDialog" runat="server"/>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

No need for the `class` attribute then

Comment: this will display the div container if the user is browsing with IE, so the poster needs the opposite like V413HAV wrote

Comment: @ShogunArts.de the OP stated -> *div tag only visible/invisible when the user is browsing with IE* - and I linked to documentation which gives further options ... I have updated my answer ... does that make you happy ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one further question see my edit.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this forum. I've made the edit. I saw tour comment about accepting answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Target everything except ie..

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    Your button goes here
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class for your `<html>` element using conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE]><html class="ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

and then, assuming this button has a class `.mybutton`, you can target it like this

```
.ie .mybutton {display: none;}
```

And then you can use the same kind of targeting if you need to style anything else differently in IE.

Comment: I also add class for safari and chrome since they too have their problems. That way all the differences can be the same way as the popular .ie class on html, like .chrome .mybutton { display: none; }. You just can't use conditional comments to target chrome or safari so I just use javascript to browser sniff some people have been turning their nose down to browser sniffing lately so you can look into it and decide for yourself.